# Thermal capacitance and resistance of conductive material

Tags: ltspice, thermistor

In my spare time I am working on this project:
I have a strip of conductive fabric material wrapped around my wrist that gets hot when current flows.
In addition to the measurements you follow with instruments in the lab, I would like to try to simulate its behavior on LTSpice with the classic model I give below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPOKAu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Is this model correct? Is there anything missing?

How do I choose parameter values highlighted in yellow:

1. Rxs
2. Rse
3. Cs
4. Cx
5. Rxe

Here the [NTC](https://www.vishay.com/docs/29049/ntcle100.pdf) that I am using.

Comment: Curious, how many thermistors are involved?  And is there a particular reason NTC was chosen, over say PTC or plain-old resistors?  Having a few more details available like supply voltage/current might help understanding and result in a better model.

Comment: There are no special requirements and I used that NTC because I had it at home ... it's an amateur project so nothing to sell or anything else important. Forn now one NTC .. but I could add another NTC (so two in total)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The model is incomplete. Missing are, at least:

1. The heater itself.
2. The body core that stabilizes the wrist temperature.
   The wrist is like a blood-cooled radiator.

I'd also add the heater-to-NTC thermal resistance, unless the NTC is really well decoupled from the heater.

I'd modify the model as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhrF3M.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The thermal resistance of the heater is negligible.

A slightly better model would have two thermal constants for the blood-to-wrist heat flow:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flOAqa.png)</sup>

As for how the values are "chosen": they have to be measured, just as in any other circuit that's only available in a physical form. And, just as with an electronic circuit measurement, there are parasitics that are not modeled.

For details about fitting a model to a physical system, you may google topics related to thermal model identification.

At the very least, you'll need to measure as many temperatures as possible - so environment *E* and body core *B* in addition to surficial wrist *X*. You'll want to add sensor models to all those measurements, so you'll end up with *SE* - the environment temp sensor, *SB* - the body core temp sensor, *SX* - the surficial wrist sensor. The temperature of deep wrist is out of reach - but that's not a problem, since the R.BD*C.D time constant will show up in the surficial wrist measurements.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! Very kind.  What do you mean with "heater"? (I'm not English, so I might be confusing this term) ..

Comment: Heater is a device that generates heat. So in this case, the heater is the conductive material that gets hot when you pass current through it.

Comment: Why doesn't the heater have its own thermal capacity in the model you included?

Comment: @KaleM Mostly because it's negligible in such a simple model - the other sources of error dwarf whatever the heater's capacity would change. It's a lightweight sheet of fabric.

Comment: While the thermal capacitances and resistances of the wrist and body cannot be found on the internet? For simplicity (I'm a hobbyist, I don't have to sell anything on the market) I would approximate them to constants, although they probably change from person to person. For example: https://thermopedia.com/content/587/